# Adjusting font and other graphical parameters in Choroplethr

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I am using the Choroplethr package to generate some maps for a forthcoming publication. Does anyone know how to adjust the graphical parameters of the outputted graphics? (Specifically, I am hoping to change the font to the journal-required font.)

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(ggplot2)

data(county.regions)
texas.counties<-county.regions[county.regions$state.name=="texas",]

fakedata<-as.data.frame(texas.counties$region)
fakedata$value<-runif(n=254, min=0, max=1)
colnames(fakedata)[1]<-"region"

county_choropleth(fakedata,
                  state_zoom = c("texas"),
                  num_colors=1,
                  legend = "test")
```

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntqpe.png)

So in this particular example, I'm hoping to change the font displayed in the legend ("test", "0.25," "0.50," "0.75").

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please specify what you would like to change the font to? Behind the scenes `choroplethr` uses ggplot2. So, presumably, you can change the font to be anything ggplot2 supports. But as I have not experimented with these features in ggplot2, I am not sure how to experiment with this.

Comment: I would like to change the font to Times New Roman. Knowing that choroplethr uses ggplot2 behind the scenes is a big help though. In that case, it sounds like I can change the font using ggplot's "theme()" feature. Will experiment now and close the question if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Adding and editing the theme() argument from ggplot2 worked. Although I imagine there are alternative ways to set the font, I am pasting the code I used and corresponding output below in case helpful to others.

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
library(ggplot2)

data(county.regions)
texas.counties<-county.regions[county.regions$state.name=="texas",]

fakedata<-as.data.frame(texas.counties$region)
fakedata$value<-runif(n=254, min=0, max=1)
colnames(fakedata)[1]<-"region"

county_choropleth(fakedata,
                  state_zoom = c("texas"),
                  num_colors=1,
                  legend = "test") + theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"))
```

[Updated Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g19bq.png)

Comment: This looks good to me. All choroplethr functions return a ggplot2 object, which means you can modify the final output by adding `+ <blah>` at the end. So I expected the solution to look something like this, although I did not how to change the font off the top of my head.